# Solr boost query (bq) not working properly

Tags: solr, solr4

I have solr docs having these two field:

```
seller_id 
rater_id
```

These fields are defined in schema.xml as such :

```
<field name="seller_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="false" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="rater_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="false" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true"/>
```

Now when I am running a query on solr with

```
<core_name>/select?defType=dismax&q.alt=\*:*&**bq=seller_id:(1053 OR 1142)^900 rater_id:(1053 OR 1142)^700**&rows=2&start=0&fl=seller_id,rater_id,id&debugQuery=true
```

I am getting following output:

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">940_RR591</str>
    <str name="seller_id">940</str>
    <str name="rater_id">1053</str>
</doc>
<doc>
    <str name="id">1142_0</str>
    <str name="seller_id">1142</str>
</doc>
```

What I am expecting is just opposite order of this.

Debug query specific output is :

```
    <lst name="explain"><str name="940_RR591">
1.8399739 = (MATCH) sum of:
  8.860351E-5 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of:
    8.860351E-5 = queryNorm
  1.8398854 = (MATCH) product of:
    3.6797707 = (MATCH) sum of:
      3.6797707 = (MATCH) weight(rater_id:1053 in 4) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
        3.6797707 = score(doc=4,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
          0.4777326 = queryWeight, product of:
            7.7025743 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1629)
            0.06202246 = queryNorm
          7.7025743 = fieldWeight in 4, product of:
            1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
              1.0 = termFreq=1.0
            7.7025743 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1629)
            1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=4)
    0.5 = coord(1/2)
</str><str name="1142_0">
1.6587491 = (MATCH) sum of:
  8.860351E-5 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of:
    8.860351E-5 = queryNorm
  1.6586605 = (MATCH) product of:
    3.317321 = (MATCH) sum of:
      3.317321 = (MATCH) weight(seller_id:1142 in 422) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
        3.317321 = score(doc=422,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
          0.51432836 = queryWeight, product of:
            6.4498115 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=1629)
            0.07974316 = queryNorm
          6.4498115 = fieldWeight in 422, product of:
            1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
              1.0 = termFreq=1.0
            6.4498115 = idf(docFreq=6, maxDocs=1629)
            1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=422)
    0.5 = coord(1/2)
</str></lst>
```

Comment: I am new in solr and not able to understand debug query well. The only significant thing I am understanding is final score.

Comment: so you asking why scores are not what you expect them to be?

Comment: @Mysterion, what i have read is solr gives output in descending order of score. Here also unexpected doc has score of 1.8399739 (higher than second doc's score).(even though as per boost, second doc should score more)

Comment: yes, I am asking same

Comment: Try pasting your complete debug output in http://explain.solr.pl/ - it's usually very helpful to understand result scores.

Comment: @Yann, here is link : http://explain.solr.pl/explains/s95pnu6u
I was expecting forth doc to come first as boost on 1142 as seller_id is higher.

Comment: The scores are almost identical; not sure what's going on. Can you try pasting an explain link to the same query, with different boost values? E.g. use 3 and 2 instead of 900 and 700. Also it's more common to query for something other than *:*, except when you positively need to get all your documents back in the response.

Comment: @Yann, with 3 and 2, I am getting expected output with all 1142 (as seller_id) docs coming on top.

Comment: I can't find out how exactly boosts are used in the final score, but I'm guessing the ratio 900/700 that you had previously is not large enough to get the order you want; the 3/2 ratio is bigger.